# Extra line when drawing an arc in swift

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, cgcontext

I have this kind of code in a swift app and I get an extra greyed line reaching the starting point of the arc.
The arc itself is drawn as expected, but it seems like `CGContextMoveToPoint` is leaving some trace behind before reaching the starting point.

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    var centerX,centerY,startAngle,endAngle,radius:CGFloat
     startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_4)
    endAngle = -startAngle
    radius = (rect.height/2) / sin(startAngle)
    centerX = rect.width/2 + (radius*cos(startAngle))
    centerY = rect.height/2
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rect.width/2, rect.height)
    CGContextAddArc(context,centerX,centerY,radius,startAngle,endAngle,0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
}
```

Any idea of what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature of `CGContextAddArc`.  From the documentation:

> If the current path already contains a subpath, Quartz adds a line
>   connecting the current point to the starting point of the arc. If the
>   current path is empty, Quartz creates a new new subpath with a
>   starting point set to the starting point of the arc.

By moving to a point, you have established the starting point of the path.  If you remove the `CGContextMoveToPoint()`, your arc will draw without the extra line.

Alternatively, you could move to the starting point of the arc:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, centerX + radius*cos(startAngle), centerY + radius*sin(startAngle))
```

---

**Update**

(Editors note:  I added this bit after @Michel figured out the problem.  This is perhaps the answer I should have given after some discussion in the comments.  It is provided here to perhaps help someone else in the future).

Your entire arc looks like the letter c, but only part of it is visible in the view (given the code above). The extra line is drawing from the middle of the bottom of the view to the lower start of the c curve which is offscreen.

If you want only the part of the arc that is in the view, then your starting angle should be `3 * M_PI_4` and your `centerX` calculation needs to then use `-` instead of `+`:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    var centerX,centerY,startAngle,endAngle,radius:CGFloat
    startAngle = 3 * CGFloat(M_PI_4)
    endAngle = -startAngle
    radius = (rect.height/2) / sin(startAngle)
    centerX = rect.width/2 - (radius*cos(startAngle))
    centerY = rect.height/2
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rect.width/2, rect.height)
    CGContextAddArc(context,centerX,centerY,radius,startAngle,endAngle,0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
}
```

Then, your starting point will be in the view and no extra line will appear.

Comment: I understand that by moving to a point, I establish the starting point of the path. But the problem is that I get a line before that point I am moving to.
In other word the point I am moving to is the starting point of the arc. At least that is my intention.

Comment: You aren't moving to the starting point of the arc.  The arc will start at point `(centerX + radius*cos(startAngle), centerY + radius*sin(startAngle))` but you are moving to `(rect.width/2, rect.height)`.  Note that the starting point of your arc is out of the view to the right of the view, so Quartz first draws the line from `(rect.width/2, rect.height)` to the staring point of the arc (which is off the view to the right).

Comment: Have you tried removing the `CGContextMoveToPoint()` or changing it to my suggestion?  How did that work for you?

Comment: I will look again, because I think namely `(rect.width/2, rect.height)` and `(centerX + radius*cos(startAngle), centerY + radius*sin(startAngle))` as you write should be the same point. So I think like you. If they are not the same point, then I may have made a mistake at some stage.
By the way what makes you say "the starting point of your arc is out of the view "?

Comment: I played with your code quite a bit.  Your entire arc looks like the letter `c`, but only part of it is visible in the view (given the code above).  The extra line is drawing from the middle of the bottom of the view to the lower start of the `c` curve which is offscreen.

Comment: I don't know what size your `view` is, but for a 100x100 view, `(rect.width/2, rect.height)` is `(50.0, 100.0)` and `(centerX + radius*cos(startAngle), centerY + radius*sin(startAngle))` is `(150.0, 100.0)` which is out of the view.

Comment: @Michel, are you intentionally only drawing part of your arc in the view, or do you want to see the whole "c"?

Comment: My experiments and what you write are on the same wave length, I am drawing a C-like curve partly outside of the display. But this is not what I want. My rect is simply the entire display and my curve should be an arc going from the middle of one side of the display to the middle of the opposite side, and it should be entirely visible. I need to check my code again, I am certainly making a confusion on the way I use the coordinates.

Comment: I finally made it work the way I want, I was making some mistakes, in the angle choice, probably a lack of concentration or confusion with the display turned upside down :). Anyway, thanks a lot for your help with appropriate remarks. I gave you the accepted answer, though in fact rather than the answer (saying what I already knew), it was your comments that were the most helpful making me looking in the right direction.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working and that my comments were helpful.  Thanks for working with me instead of just dismissing my answer which told you what you already knew.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a solution that alters the `startAngle` to perhaps help someone else in the future.  You might want to compare it to your solution to see how they are the same or differ.