# Creating UIBezierPath from an arc adds extra line

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw a rounded rect filled with black. But instead it has a lot of white inside. The problem is that `BezierPath(arcCenter:...)` closes the path, even though `close()` is not called.

[image]
[image]

In the second picture I removed one section so that the structure could be seen. My shape consists of 4 lines and 4 little arcs.

I've managed to find these answers, none of which help. I guess they solve the question asked, however none of them explain what's going on, and how to avoid this extra line in general.

[addArc(withCenter) closing path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756457/addarcwithcenter-closing-path?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[How can I prevent closing Bezier Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006716/how-can-i-prevent-closing-bezier-path?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Extra line when drawing an arc in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489157/extra-line-when-drawing-an-arc-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The code I'm using for each of the arcs goes like this

```
let extent = CGFloat(startAngle) // -1.5707963267948966
let end = extent + CGFloat(arcAngle) // 0
let cx = CGFloat(x + w / 2)
let cy = CGFloat(y + h / 2)
let maxSize = CGFloat(max(w, h))
let path = MBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: maxSize / 2, startAngle: extent, endAngle: end, clockwise: arcAngle >= 0)

var transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: cx, y: cy)
transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(rotation))
path.apply(transform.scaledBy(x: CGFloat(w) / maxSize, y: CGFloat(h) / maxSize))

bezierPath.append(path)
```

Requested edits

1. The path I'm drawing is in svg format

   `<path d="M 140 25 L 220 25 A 10 20 0 0 1 230 45 L 230 105 A 10 20 0 0 1 220 125 L 140 125 A 10 20 0 0 1 130 105 L 130 45 A 10 20 0 0 1 140 25 L 220 25 " fill="black"  stroke="red" />`

values seen in debugger for 4 corners in order of appearance:

extent = -pi/2, 0, pi/2, pi

end = 0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2

2. Path is drawn using CGContext's drawPath method. And it works fine on countless other paths. And it is filled like this `ctx!.drawPath(using: .fill)`
3. `MBezierPath` is a typedef. `public typealias MBezierPath = UIBezierPath` sorry about that. Everything in question happens in open source Macaw library.

I'll try to state the problem more clearly. See the arc on the lower left of the second picture. The arc itself is red and it is also filled with black in a way allowing to suggest that there is an extra line connecting the ends of an arc. If there were to be the real line it would be red as well, so that is not the case, however there clearly is something that I don't need there.

May I also add that `bezierPath.addArc(withCenter:...)` does not close the path and everything works fine. However in this case I have to use `BezierPath(arcCenter:...)` to create a separate path, because I need to apply transform matrix, and only after that I can add this arc path to the path containing the rest of the shape.

Comment: Please add more code, like how you're filling the color.

Comment: Add more code, whats x, y startAngle, and everything else .

Comment: What is an `MBezierPath`? Is that some third party framework object? It's not a Foundation class object, that's for sure.